# Find text in presentation and bring into view in the active window

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to duplicate the behavior of the 'Find' button in Powerpoint 2007. I have been able to write vba to find the text I am searching for, but I would like to bring the shape containing the text to the center of the main window. My code selects the correct slide and shape, it is just not visible.

```
ppt.Presentations.open(strFloorPlan)
For each sld in ppt.Activepresentation.Slides
    For each shp in sld.shapes
        if shp.hasTextFrame then
            set txtrng =  shp.textFrame.TextRange
            set foundtext =txtrnd.Find(findwhat:="A string representing my search criteria)
            do while not (foundtext is nothing)
                sld.select      'This works
                shape.select    'This works

             **At this point I have my text selected, but is off screen. I would like                  it to be in the current ppt window, so the users do not net to find it.**

            Loop
         End if
     Next
Next
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Added to my original post

Answer (score 1):

This'll get you close:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height
```

It makes sure that the area bounded by the coordinates you supply (ie, the shape's coordinates) are fully in view.  It doesn't center the shape in the current view, however.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect for my needs. Boy do I miss a macro recorder in PPT 2007-2010. I am a new user of Stackoverflow, is there some way to give you points for your help.

Comment: Accept answer and/or up vote Steve's answer gives him points.

Comment: Glad it gets you there.  The old macro recorder wouldn't have picked this one up anyhow, so for once, you're not missing anything. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add below to change the Shape location your search finds to the center of the screen (provided that the shape is smaller than the presentation):

```
shp.Top = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - shp.Height) / 2
shp.Left = (ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - shp.Width) / 2
```

Comment: The above code moves the shape to the center of the window. I do not want to move the shape, just make the shape visible in the ppt window. I am doing this from an Access app, finding the seat location for employees. Thank you for your interest.